# Evaluating limits of exponential functions

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am just wondering how to evaluate these limits. I am aware that the method I said is not mathematically acceptable as we do not have $\infty$ as powers etc. but I just want to see whether that make sense logically. I gave these limits and the procedure what I think and answers. Please comment whether I am right.

$$
 \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-ax} = \frac{1}{e^{a \infty}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0 \\ \\
\lim_{x\to0} e^{-ax} = \big (e^{0} \big )^{-a} = \frac{1}{\big (e^{0} \big )^{a}}=1
$$

Comment: Your first line is fully true if $a>0$ and completly false if not!

Comment: The second line is true and there is no  indeterminate form since $e^0=1$ is defined as a real number. The unique problem you have is when $a$ is negative or equal to 0. If $a=0$ your function is constant and there is no problem which deserves to be mentionned. If $a$ negative....

Comment: Also $\lim_{x\to0} e^{-ax} = e^{-a0} = e^0 = 1 $

Comment: yes in above expressions, `a>0`

Answer (score 2):

For every $a\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^{-ax}= e^{0} =1$$
If $a\lt 0$, then
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} e^{-ax}= e^{\infty} =\infty $$
If $a=0$, then
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} e^{-ax}= e^{0} =1 $$
If $a\gt 0$, then
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} e^{-ax}= \frac{1}{e^{\infty}} =0 $$